# Howto hide/disable fields not needed

Tags: fields, core

My company does not make use of many of the fields provided by civicrm. Our users told me the sheer mass of empty fields is overwhelming them.

I know I could walk the hide-by-jquery-to-death way, but:

Is there a designated or recommended way to disable or hide civi core fields like "nickname" or "legal_name"?

Comment: Now 2018, going into 2019, still no answer on that feature?

Comment: civicrm is largely built by the community - if the community have not provided a feature you want then perhaps not many folk are fussed enough to put together a solution. Hmm just remembered about the new extension so have added an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "hide-by-jquery-to-death" way is the way to go for now. (Great name :) )

There are discussions to do that via the web interface in a future version, but that's not there yet.

Comment: Yap. I'm afraid, you're right.

Answer (score 11):

You can hide some of them via the UI at **Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences**

e.g. http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

[image: Display Preferences]

Answer (score 5):

The new Extension called [Contact Summary Layout Editor](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout) is a new tool that may help folk dealing with this type of problem

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can create a modified version of the default contact page templates [as described here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in,+Profile,+Contribution+and+Event+Registration+Screens).

*Excerpt from that page:*

> These steps are for any "built-in" screen (e.g. the Contact Summary
>   screen)...
>
> - Navigate to the screen you want to customize and use your browser to View Source.
> - Search for ".tpl" in the source. You will find a comment line which gives you the path and name of the template used for the screen you
>     are viewing.
>
> `<!-- .tpl file invoked: CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.tpl. Call via
>   form.tpl if we have a form in the page. -->`
>
> - Locate this file on your server under your ../civicrm/templates path. Make a copy of file in the equivalent path under your new custom
>     templates directory.
> - Edit the file as needed and save.
> - Then clean-up the compiled templates directory, usually by deleting all the directories under your templates_c directory. You can also do
>     the cleanup by enabling CiviCRM debugging and running the directory
>     cleanup command. (NOTE: You do NOT need to delete the standard version
>     of the template from your main CiviCRM codebase. CiviCRM will look for
>     a customized version first, and use that one if found.)
> - You should see your modified version when you reload the CiviCRM screen. If you need help with the templating language, check out the
>     [Smarty Documentation](http://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll do this at some places but because those fields happen to be displayed in various contexts I hope with js/jquery I'll be able to catch some more occurences in a single place.

Answer (score 2):

Some example code if you want to remove certain elements on the contact add and edit forms:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_buildForm().
 *
 * Changes some fields on the add and update contact forms
 *
 * @param string $formName
 * @param CRM_Core_Form $form
 */
function MODULE_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  // print_r($formName);
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contact_Form_Contact') {
    if (($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) || ($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::UPDATE)) {
      // print_r($form);
      // Add a javascript file for changes in display
      CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptUrl('https://EXAMPLE.ORG/sites/all/themes/EXAMPLE/EXAMPLE.js');

      // Remove field override geocoding
      for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        if ($form->elementExists('address[' . $i . '][manual_geo_code]')) {
          $form->removeElement('address[' . $i . '][manual_geo_code]');
          // $element = &$form->getElement('address[1][manual_geo_code]');
          // crm_Core_error::debug( 'options', $element->_options );
          // also you can add new options w/ $element->addOption( );
        }
      }

      // Remove field signature text
      for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        if ($form->elementExists('email[' . $i . '][signature_text]')) {
          $form->removeElement('email[' . $i . '][signature_text]');
        }
      }

      // Remove field signature html
      for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        if ($form->elementExists('email[' . $i . '][signature_html]')) {
          $form->removeElement('email[' . $i . '][signature_html]');
        }
      }

      // Remove field external id
      if ($form->elementExists('external_identifier')) {
        $form->removeElement('external_identifier');
      }

      // Remove field nickname
      if ($form->elementExists('nick_name')) {
        $form->removeElement('nick_name');
      }

      if ($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
        // we can get the contact type from the url ct parameter: Individual/household/organisation
        $contactType = CRM_Utils_Array::value('ct', $_GET, '0');
      }

      elseif ($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::UPDATE) {
        // there is no info in the url so we need to use the contact id and check
        $contactId = CRM_Utils_Array::value('cid', $_GET, '0');
        if ($contactId != 0) {
          $contactType = CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::getContactType($contactId);
          // $subType = CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::getContactSubType($contactId);
        }
      }

      // Household
      if ($contactType == 'Household') {
        // Remove custom block
        unset($form->_groupTree[3]);
        // Remove custom block
        unset($form->_groupTree[7]);
        // Change label of household name
        if ($form->elementExists('household_name')) {
          $element = &$form->getElement('household_name');
          $element->setLabel('NEW LABEL');
        }
      }
      elseif ($contactType == 'Organization') {
        // Remove custom block
        unset($form->_groupTree[1]);
        // Remove custom block
        unset($form->_groupTree[7]);
        if ($form->elementExists('sic_code')) {
          $form->removeElement('sic_code');
        }
      }
      else {
        // Individual
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm afraid that this is too much afford if we take the frontend migration plans of civicrm into account.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "too much effort". First: this code does a lot more than just remove a simple "nickname" field. Second: the effort of writing code becomes very little once you know how to do it and I think this is a nice example how to do it in a way that targets in a futureproof way the right fields without creating issues with future upgrades of civi.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not want to question your approach in general. It's just I'm not trusting this old form builder stuff to be future proof.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Hans Rossel](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/37689/)'s helpful answer, below are paired PHP and javascript to remove some contact fields when adding or editing contacts.

Note there is a WordPress-specific function call to obtain the path to the javascript file, which I assume is stored in the `.../plugins/CUSTOMPLUGIN/assets/` folder, with a `define('WP_CUSTOMPLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__);` directive in the main plugin PHP file.

**PHP hook**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_buildForm().
 *
 * Changes some fields on the add and update contact forms
 *
 * @param string $formName
 * @param CRM_Core_Form $form
 */
function MODULE_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
    if ($formName !== 'CRM_Contact_Form_Contact') {
        return;
    }
    if (($form->getAction() !== CRM_Core_Action::ADD) && ($form->getAction() !== CRM_Core_Action::UPDATE)) {
        return;
    }
    // ***WORDPRESS-SPECIFIC: javascript for contacts edit page
    $jsUrl = plugins_url('assets/cv_editcntct.js', WP_CUSTOMPLUGIN_FILE);
    CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptUrl($jsUrl);

    // Remove some address fields
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        // geocoding
        if ($form->elementExists('address[' . $i . '][geo_code_1]')) {
            $form->removeElement('address[' . $i . '][geo_code_1]');
            $form->removeElement('address[' . $i . '][geo_code_2]');
        }

        // county
        if ($form->elementExists('address[' . $i . '][county_id]')) {
            $form->removeElement('address[' . $i . '][county_id]');
        }
    }

    // See also cv_editcntct.js
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        // Remove field signature text
        if ($form->elementExists('email[' . $i . '][signature_text]')) {
                $form->removeElement('email[' . $i . '][signature_text]');
        }
        // Remove field signature html
        if ($form->elementExists('email[' . $i . '][signature_html]')) {
                $form->removeElement('email[' . $i . '][signature_html]');
        }
    }

    if ($form->elementExists('employer_id')) {
        $form->removeElement('employer_id');
    }
    if ($form->elementExists('job_title')) {
        $form->removeElement('job_title');
    }
    if ($form->elementExists('image_URL')) {
        $form->removeElement('image_URL');
    }

    $contactType = NULL;
    if ($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::ADD) {
        // we can get the contact type from the url ct parameter: Individual/household/organisation
        $contactType = CRM_Utils_Array::value('ct', $_GET, '0');
    }
    elseif ($form->getAction() == CRM_Core_Action::UPDATE) {
        // there is no info in the url so we need to use the contact id and check
        $contactId = CRM_Utils_Array::value('cid', $_GET, '0');
        if ($contactId != 0) {
            $contactType = CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::getContactType($contactId);
            //$subType = CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::getContactSubType($contactId);
        }
    }

    // Adjustments specific to contact type...
    if ($contactType == 'Household') {
        // no Household customizations
    }
    elseif ($contactType == 'Organization') {
        // // Remove custom block
        // unset($form->_groupTree[1]);
        if ($form->elementExists('sic_code')) {
            $form->removeElement('sic_code');
        }
    }
    else {
        // Individual
        // // Remove field nickname
        // if ($form->elementExists('nick_name')) {
        //  $form->removeElement('nick_name');
        // }
    }
}
```

**Javascript** `cv_editcntct.js` **file**

```
(function($, undefined){
    //console.log('hello from cv_editcntct.js');

    // for individual: employer and job title has been removed
    // adjust layout with or without nickname
    var $st = $('#contact_sub_type');
    var $nn = $st.closest('tr').find('#nick_name');
    if ($nn.length) {
        // remove all (empty) TD cells prior to nickname and adjust width
        var $td = $nn.closest('td').attr('colspan','2');
        $td.prevAll().remove();
        $nn.css('width',$td.width()+'px');
        // also adjust subtype width
        $td = $st.closest('td').attr('colspan','3');
        $st.css('width',$td.width()+'px');
    } else {
        // remove empty TD cells before subtype, and adjust subtype width
        var $td = $st.closest('td').attr('colspan','3');
        $td.prevAll().remove();
        $st.css('width',$td.width()+'px');
    }
    
    // remove (empty) image URL section (table)
    $('table.image_URL-section').remove();

    // remove (empty) signature blocks
    $('.email-signature.crm-collapsible').remove();
    // since new emails can be added, monitor the DOM for added elements 
    // and remove signature blocks
    $emailSection = $('.crm-section.contact_information-section');
    if ($emailSection.length) {
        // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
        const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
            // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
            var bAdded = false;
            for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
                    bAdded = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bAdded) {
                // remove (empty) signature blocks
                var $s = $('.email-signature.crm-collapsible');
                if ($s.length) {
                    $s.remove();
                    console.log("Zapped a signature block!");
                }
            }
        };
        // Create a DOM observer
        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        // Start watching for element additions (or removals) in the email section
        observer.observe($emailSection.get(0), { childList: true, subtree: true }); 
    }

})(jQuery);
```