# CRM API shows only the first char of the result?

Tags: custom-fields, api

I'm absolutely embarrassed. I try to get value as it in [this thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-can-i-add-rearrange-custom-fields-in-the-default-contact-view-template/26391) (and sorry for the wrong use of the topic).

I try get a custom value via CRM API. With the API Explorer I can create the expression:

```
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Contact' action='getvalue' sequential=0 return="custom_13" id=$contactId}
{foreach from=$result.values item=contact}
  {$contact.some_field}
{/foreach}
```

I can see the right result in the API Explorer. I insert it as it is into my tpl file, and I get back only the first character of the result.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using getvalue, $result will be the contact's custom_13 value, so you don't need a foreach loop.

Try using below snippet

```
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Contact' action='getvalue' sequential=0 return="custom_13" id=$contactId}
Custom 13: {$result}
```

Pradeep